# Angular 5: Multiple requests at once with forkJoin

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular5

---

**Importand node**

**Was a problem within the back end, not angular, requests are correct.**

---

I like to upload different files at once in my angular5 app. To do this I use `rsjx forkJoin`. I append the request in an array as you can see in the following code.

After adding the request to the array, they are all the same requests, meaning that I upload one file multiple times instead of the different selected files. Before I add them to the array, you can see in the screenshot, it's fine, different request are created by the service. I know this is some kind of pointer problem, but I have no idea how to fix this, I tried to make a deep copy with `Object.assign({}, request)`, but doesn't work for the `Observable`.

Console log ~ ~ (ignore the error, the server refuses always the second request because of some unique constraint requirement - it is correct): ~ ~

[image]

The component code:

```
uploadFiles() {
  var requests = [];
  var ctrNoFailuer = this.filesReplace.length;

  for (var i = 0; i < this.filesReplace.length; i++) {
    let request = this.solutionFileService.update(this.filesReplace[i][0], this.filesReplace[i][1]);
    console.log(request);
    requests.push(request);
  }

  if (requests.length == 0) {
    this.runTests();
  } else {
    forkJoin(requests).subscribe(
      res => {
        // [...]
      }
    )
  }
}
```

The service looks like this:

```
update(solutionFile: SolutionFile, file?: File): Observable<SolutionFile> {
  console.log(solutionFile);
  let url = `${this.url}/src_uploads/${solutionFile.id}/`;

  if (file) {
    let headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'enctype': 'multipart/form-data',
      'Authorization': `JWT ${this.authService.getToken()}`
    })

    const formData: FormData = new FormData();
    formData.append('student_solution', String(solutionFile.student_solution));
    formData.append('file_src', file, file.name);

    return this.httpClient.put<SolutionFile>(url, formData, { headers: headers })
      .pipe(
        catchError(this.handleError('UPDATE solution-file', new SolutionFile()))
      );
  }

  return this.httpClient.put<SolutionFile>(url, solutionFile, { headers: this.headers })
    .pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError('UPDATE solution-file', new SolutionFile())
    )
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems correct, although you can make some improvements (factorisation, syntax ...), such as this :

```
uploadFiles() {
  const requests = this.filesReplace.map(fr => this.solutionFileService.update(fr[0], fr[1]));

  if (!requests.length) {
    this.runTests();
  } else {
    forkJoin(requests).subscribe(
      res => {
        // [...]
      }
    )
  }
}

update(solutionFile: SolutionFile, file ?: File): Observable < SolutionFile > {
  let url = `${this.url}/src_uploads/${solutionFile.id}/`;

  const headers = file ?
    new HttpHeaders({
      'enctype': 'multipart/form-data',
      'Authorization': `JWT ${this.authService.getToken()}`
    }) : this.headers;

  const formData: FormData = new FormData();
  formData.append('student_solution', String(solutionFile.student_solution));
  formData.append('file_src', file, file && file.name || undefined);

  const payload = file ? formData : solutionFile;

  return this.httpClient.put<SolutionFile>(url, payload, { headers })
    .pipe(
      catchError(() => this.handleError('UPDATE solution-file', new SolutionFile()))
    );
}
```

Also, please post your logs as text, because not everyone has access to imgur. Did you try to log the result of the `forkJoin` call ?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't fully understood the question, but as I understood the forkJoin is not working for you, because you trying to pass array of observables. To overcome that issue, try to **apply** array of observables:

```
 forkJoin.apply(this, requests).subscribe(
```

Hope this helps